# Правильний переклад слова "шаровидная"

Tags: переклад, правопис

Допоможіть, будь ласка, зробити правильний переклад слова ***"шаровидная"***, в такому речені:*"Клен пальмолистий - листопадне декоративне дерево з "шаровидной" формою крони, висотою та шириною 2,5-3 м й яскраво-зеленою корою."*

Знайшла декілька варіантів перекладу: *[кулястий (куляста)](http://sum.in.ua/s/kuljastyj), кулеподібна, шаровидна, кулевидна та шароподібна.*

Який з варіантів буде правильно використати?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Кулястий* і *кулеподібний* - це синоніми. Ще один синонім - це *[кульовий](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)*.

> **Шаровой** – кульови́й;
>   • *ш., шарообразный* – куля́стий.

Отже,

> з *кулястою* формою крони

Якщо є сумніви, то можна використати [сферична](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=spherical&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on).